# How to add time onto the 'load' event listener so preloading intro of website is always seen?

Tags: javascript

```
let loader = document.getElementById("preloader");

window.addEventListener("load", function () { loader.style.display = "none"; });
```

I am trying to create an preloader intro for my webpage that is just a div with a background gif, but the page always loads too fast to see it.

I am unsure of how to add time onto the load or if I need to use a different function to achieve the result I'm after.

Comment: tried changing the throttling to slow 3G in your browser network?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)!. Here I hide the preloader with a function only after both things are true: window is loaded and a 2 second timeout has run.

```js
let loaded = false
let enoughTimePassed = false

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if (enoughTimePassed) { hidePreloader() }
  loaded = true
})

setTimeout(() => {
  if (loaded) { hidePreloader() }
  enoughTimePassed = true
}, 2000)

function hidePreloader() {
   document.getElementById("preloader").remove()
}
```

```css
#preloader {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader">Loading...</div>
<div>LOADED</div>
```